# Why does this char value not convert to datetime?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an instance of Performance Monitor saving data to a table on a MS SQL server database. The performance data is saved to a table called CounterData. The table has a char(24) field (counterdatetime) for storing the date/time of the data. I'm trying to treat that field as a datetime data, but I keep getting "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Here is an example of data from the counterdatetime: 2019-07-02 09:19:46.300

I have tried different variations of CAST and CONVERT to allow me to handle this data as date time. For example:

```
SELECT CAST(counterdatetime as datetime) from CounterData
SELECT CAST(counterdatetime as datetime2) from CounterData
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,counterdatetime,101) from CounterData
```

Each gives me the "Conversion failed . . ." error. I thought perhaps the failure was triggered by a bogus value in one record, so I tried limiting the conversion with a WHERE expression that specifies a good value. I also tried casting the value itself, as in:

```
SELECT CAST('2019-07-02 09:19:46.300' as datetime)
```

In this instance, the CAST works.

Why doesn't it work when I select the value from the table?

UPDATE

@Jeroen Mostert provided the answer in a comment, which I posted as an answer.

Comment: "`The table has a char(24) field... I'm trying to treat that field as a datetime data`" **DON'T DO THAT!** If you have DateTime values, store them using a type from the DateTime family!

Comment: I'm not convinced that `'2019-07-02 09:19:46.300'` is the actual value which is causing your query to crash.  Are you certain of this?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Using char(24) wasn't my choice. This is how Performance Monitor created the table.

Comment: Most probably, it fails because the contents are not what you think they are. See what `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CounterDateTime)` gives you. Compare it to `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '2019-07-02 09:19:46.300')` and hunt for invisible/unprintable characters. One notable character `CONVERT` will not countenance is a newline (which will manifest as `0D0A`). Extra insidiously, SSMS will not display newlines in columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When the SELECT specifies only one field (e.g., `SELECT CAST(counterdatetime as datetime) FROM CounterData`) what other value could be causing the problem? I mean, no other value is being referenced in the SELCT, so . . . .

Comment: @DWLangham No...I'm not suggesting that another _column_ is responsible, I'm suggesting that maybe another _record_ is responsible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As stated in the original post, I did try using a WHERE expression that limited the SELECT to a single record what what looks like a good value (2019-07-02 09:19:46.300).

Comment: Well that value converts, either by `CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT`, so this is not a reproducible data point.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CounterDateTime), CounterDateTime from CounterData WHERE counterid=12 and RecordIndex=1154` returns "0x323031392D30372D30322030393A31393A34362E33303000", "2019-07-02 09:19:46.300". The query `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '2019-07-02 09:19:46.300')` returns "0x323031392D30372D30322030393A31393A34362E333030".

Comment: Uh-oh, Spaghetti-O's. That's a `NUL` character that doesn't belong there. These are extra awful because `REPLACE` doesn't know what to do with them by default. Try `CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(CounterDateTime COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, CHAR(0), ''))`. (`SUBSTRING(CounterDateTime, 1, 23)` should also work in this case, since we can expect the `NUL` to always be at the end.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert YOU ARE CORRECT!  The statement `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(CounterDateTime COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, CHAR(0), '')) FROM CounterData` returns all rows without an error. I wrapped the `CONVERT()` inside a `MONTH()` and got 7 (as expected). Thanks!

Comment: To convert everything in one go (since doing it over and over is going to be annoying): `UPDATE CounterData SET CounterDateTime = SUBSTRING(CounterDateTime, 1, 23); ALTER TABLE CounterData ALTER COLUMN CounterDateTime DATETIME` should take care of the typing. Or `INSERT` things in another table with properly typed columns. If you need a more flexible permanent setup, it should be possible to get perfmon to insert its data into a view with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that will convert the data before it has a chance to get annoying.

Answer (score 3):

I am not certain if the literal `'2019-07-02 09:19:46.300'` is the text value which is actually crashing your query.  If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, there is a helper function [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which will attempt to convert an input string to a certain type (datetime in this case), and will either return a converted datetime value, or `NULL` if the conversion failed.

Try running the following query:

```
SELECT
    counterdatetime
FROM CounterData
WHERE
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, counterdatetime) IS NULL;
```

If you see any records showing up in the result set, it means that these values cannot be successfully converted.

Comment: The query returns all the rows in the table. What I don't understand is WHY these values cannot be converted.

Comment: You need to give us a reproducible set of sample data, otherwise all we can do is make educated guesses (as I have done here).  Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: No, please edit your question so that others may also easily read the data.

Comment: See my UPDATE to the question. The literal values returned by the SELECT aren't the problem. They're fine, but it seems that the char(24) field contains something else in addition to the literal string that gets returned by SELECT.

Comment: @DWLangham It looks like you got an exact answer/fix in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss` is not an unambiguous format when using the `datetime` datatype; it changes depending on the language.

Take the below examples:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH; --American
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2019-07-06'); --Returns 06 July 2019

SET LANGUAGE BRITISH; --English
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2019-07-06'); --Returns 07 June 2019
```

If we then take a date like the below, watch what happens:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH; --American
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2019-01-31'); --Returns 01 January 2019

SET LANGUAGE British; --English
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2019-01-31'); --Conversion error
```

Really, however, you should not be storing your dates as a `char`, and you need to fix that. Fortunately, you can easily fix your data by changing it to the ISO format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sss`:

```
UPDATE CounterData
SET counterdatetime = STUFF(counterdatetime,11,1,'T');

ALTER TABLE CounterData ALTER COLUMN counterdatetime datetime;
```

Comment: Everyone, please stop preaching that I shouldn't store date value as char. I KNOW that. The choice in this case wasn't mine.

Comment: This doesn't change the main part of my question @DWLangham. `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss is` not an unambiguous, and the `STUFF` expression would make it and allow you to convert the rows successfully (provided that they are are *all* in that format),. Alternatively, if you your values are actually accurate to 1/1000 of a second, not 1/300, you use use `datetime2(3)`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion on a copy of the table with only 10 rows. The UPDATE command changed the CounterDateTime values to something like this: 2019-07-01T16:35:41.364. But the ALTER TABLE command failed with "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." I also tried specifying `datetime2` as the type for the ALTER TABLE and got the same error.

Comment: Sounds like you have rows with values that aren't in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hhh:mm:ss.sss` then @DWLangham. `TRY_CONVERT` is your friend here, but you're fighting a losing battle when you can't change the system now I'm afraid; you'd be better off talking to your system designer and getting them to fix the problem before it gets worse.

Answer (score 0):

> The table has a char(24) field... I'm trying to treat that field as a datetime data

**DON'T DO THAT!** If you have DateTime values, store them using a type from the DateTime family! Hopefully this whole thing is part of a project to *fix* (because right now, the schema really is *broken*) this table. As just one example (of many) of why this is important, indexes on this column are mostly useless as it is.

> I thought perhaps the failure was triggered by a bogus value in one record...

This is **exactly** what is happening. There is bad data. (Using a real DateTime type would prevent this from happening in the first place).

> ... so I tried limiting the conversion with a WHERE expression that specifies a good value.

Check your `WHERE` clause again, because it wasn't specific enough, or there was a problem with the value you chose you didn't see at first.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeroen Mostert provided the correct answer in a comment to the original post, so credit should go to him.

> Uh-oh, Spaghetti-O's. That's a NUL character that doesn't belong
>   there. These are extra awful because REPLACE doesn't know what to do
>   with them by default. Try CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(CounterDateTime
>   COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, CHAR(0), '')).
>   (SUBSTRING(CounterDateTime, 1, 23) should also work in this case,
>   since we can expect the NUL to always be at the end.)